# Are there any privately owned V-22 Ospreys?

Tags: military, private-jets, v-22

Could someone buy a [V-22 Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) and convert it to a luxury interior rather than a military one? Has anyone done that? Are there any images available of a private Osprey made to be luxurious inside? What does the interior of the [US President's Osprey](http://gizmodo.com/the-president-gets-a-personal-osprey-hes-not-allowed-t-1108783801) look like?

Answer (score 7):

There are no 'private' Ospreys thus far (all are operated by USAF, USMC and JSDF)- the Bell Boeing MV-22 Osprey used by the US Marine Corps's HMX-1 presidential helicopter squadron:

> ... will conduct presidential support missions, which means these aircraft will carry presidential support staff and news media representatives travelling with the president," the USMC says. "The Osprey mission at HMX-1 does not include carrying the President of the United States."

so I'm not counting on 'luxury' interiors. When (and if) a civil version of V-22 is produced (or if the Japanese feel like selling theirs), you can buy it and make the interior whichever way you like.

Comment: Or you could buy an [Augusta Westland AW609](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW609), which is in flight tests at the time of writing this but expected to be available privately.